# How to have multiple subclasses of MKNetworkKit?

Tags: objective-c, rest, ios5, subclassing, mknetworkkit

I am currently using MKNetworkKit to cache the download of several images from a restful server. I have another restful service I ping to get supplemental information about the images. Whichever server I ping first works, but when pinging the second server I get the following error:

> [The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 404.)]
>   2012-08-12 19:51:12.340 [51853:11603]
>
> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 404.)" UserInfo=0x73c5490 {Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1, Content-Length=47, Content-Type=text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1, Connection=keep-alive, Date=Sun, 12 Aug 2012 23:51:11 GMT}
>   2012-08-12 19:51:12.341 [MKNetworkOperation operationFailedWithError:] [Line 1280] State: 0

MKNetworkKit is pinging the first server in attempt to get data from the second server's URL. I think I may need to create another reachability object? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Or where I can find some example implementation of one project with multiple subclasses?

*Edit*
I implement both engines the following way:

```
@implementation FirstEngine

FirstEngine* _sharedEngine;

+(FirstEngine*)sharedEngine
{
    if(_sharedEngine==nil)
    {
        _sharedEngine = [[FirstEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"***.**.**.**" customHeaderFields:nil];            
    }
    return _sharedEngine;
}
```

and invoke them this way:

```
$[[FirstEngine sharedEngine] bodyForPath:url verb:verb body:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary* body)
{}....
```

or

```
$[[SecondEngine sharedEngine] bodyForPath:url verb:verb body:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary* body)
{}....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a MKNetworkEngine object in your AppDelegate for "every" server you talk to.

```
self.imageCacheEngine = [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"images.myserver.com"];
```

and

```
self.apiEngine =  [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"api.myserver.com"];
```

Enqueue image requests to the imageCacheEngine and api requests to your apiEngine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I do this, considering code edits posted above?

Comment: You shouldn't override sharedEngine. After creating engines in AppDelegate, use something like [AppDelegate.engine imageAtURL…]